# UITextView last line position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uitextview

I faced with the next problem: I have a `UITableView` with custom cell that has an `UITextView`. After the user starts typing, a last line is overlapping with a keyboard, that has an input accessory view. So I have to calculate a difference between the keyboard top and the last line `.y` position and assign this value to tableView contentInset.
The question is how can I figure out a rect or position of the text view last line?

I have ordinary notifications for listening keyboard:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(_toggleKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(_toggleKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

And the next method where I have to calculate all that stuff:

```
@objc private func _toggleKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary?
    let rectValue = info![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let kbSize = rectValue.cgRectValue
    let kbFrame = view.convert(kbSize, from: view.window)
    
    // val = bottom .y of last text view line
    // keyboard .top - val = diff
    // contentInsets.bottom = diff
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Any screenshot/vid of the issue which would explain the problem further? Initially I'd say it has something to do with constraints and safe-inset, but could be various problems without more context.

Comment: Well this is great question. Please provide your code.

Comment: When I faced a similar task, I relied on the bottom of the `UITextView` itself. I even lifted it up a few points, so visually it was right on top of the keyboard.

Comment: @PaulPeelen I have the following layout: table view cell with only UITextView, that has left, top, right and bottom fixed constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

```
let textPosition = textView.endOfDocument
let rect = textView.caretRect(for: textPosition)
```